# How to checkout a SVN repo in the same server?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I am currently working on a website and I am hosting it on a server, the server has an SVN repository of the project.
What I am currently doing is work on a local repository copy and upload it via ftp to the development sub-domain.
So I wanted to ask if there was a way to checkout the SVN repo directly on the same server.

In case I wasn't clear enough this is the output of `ls` command run on the server:
`www dev svn`

where `svn/devrep` is my subversion main repository, and I want to `svn checkout` that repository to `dev` directory.

Comment: Checking out is taking a copy of the files from Repository to your destination directory. You can work on the files and check-in once done. Are you trying to create a copy of the files again IN THE REPOSITORY for version management ? or just a copy in the server FROM THE REPOSITORY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving the answers for both the scenarios, **IN THE REPOSITORY** as well as **FROM THE REPOSITORY**

**In the Repository:**(Likely)
You have the files in SVN Repository. The files are in Production(DEVREP) and you want to change some files. You want to keep your new changes separate. Hence, trying to copy the files in the repository. In SVN, this is called creating a new Branch. If you are using any UI Client like TortoiseSVN, you can create a new Branch and the files will be available in DEV as well. If you make any changes in DEV, this will not affect DEVREP.

**From the Repository:** (Unlikely, just in case if this is what you need)
This could be done as you checkout normally from the Repository to your local machine.

Comment: I wanted to checkout a copy from the repository but couldn't find a solution until I saw an example using `svn co file:///path/to/repo /sub/domain/path`.
The other scenario you mentioned would be very helpful to me as well for others readers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

from command line:

```
svn co file:///path/to/repo /sub/domain/path
```

worked fine with me